# Paypal OAuth login example doesn't work as expected

Tags: authentication, oauth, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm following [this interactive login example](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/dotnet?success=true&env=sandbox) from Paypal's site.

```
  public ActionResult PaypalResponse(string scope, string code)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        configurationMap.Add("mode", "sandbox");

        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext();
        apiContext.Config = configurationMap;

        CreateFromAuthorizationCodeParameters param = new CreateFromAuthorizationCodeParameters();
        param.setClientId(clientId);
        param.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        param.SetCode(code);

         // Exception here: 
        Tokeninfo info = Tokeninfo.CreateFromAuthorizationCode(apiContext, param);

        return null;
    }
```

The method CreateFromAuthorizationCode results in this (incorrect) call.  Note how client ID and client secret are missing

```
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
User-Agent: PayPalSDK/  ;lang=DOTNET;v=4.0.30319.18051;bit=64;os=Microsoft Windows 8 Enterprise 6.2.9200.0;
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 211
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=authorization_code&code=d2mSEzm9xvE_l9Ibho0g6FNBVrC7wHZchJWqJfY...redacted...
```

The Fiddler output is

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Length: 76
DC: origin1-api.sandbox.paypal.com
Date: Mon, 14 Oct 2013 01:30:05 GMT
Connection: close
Set-Cookie: DC=origin1-api.sandbox.paypal.com; secure

{"error_description":"client id or secret is null","error":"invalid_client"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and solved it changing call method

```
string postcontents = string.Format("client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri={2}&code={3}"
                                      , System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(clientId)
                                      , System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(secret)
                                      , System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(url)
                                      , System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(code));


        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice");
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(clientId, secret);
        request.Method = "POST";
        byte[] postcontentsArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postcontents);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postcontentsArray.Length;
        //OAuth.
        using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            requestStream.Write(postcontentsArray, 0, postcontentsArray.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
            {
                string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
                responseStream.Close();
                response.Close();
                // return SerializeToken(responseFromServer);
                dynamic dynObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
                string token = dynObj["access_token"];
                //token = ser.Deserialize<ImportContacts._Default.GoogleOAuthToken>(responseFromServer);
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I had some issues with PayPal too, albeit not with this sample. I used nodejs. [This library](https://github.com/auth0/passport-paypal-oauth) works fine, you might want to compare notes with the one you are using and see if you find any difference. (The endpoints are certainly different). See [here](https://github.com/auth0/passport-paypal-oauth/blob/master/lib/passport-paypal-oauth/strategy.js) specifically.

Answer (score 0):

updated based on @pollirrata answer, and this is how it worked for me. Hope it will help someone.

```
    //code is what you get from LoginWithPayPal login page in return (query string)
public ....  GetRefreshAccessToken(string code)
    {            
        var oAuthClientId = "clientid from paypal developer site";
        var oAuthClientSecret = "client secret from paypal developer site";
        var oAuthUrl = "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/tokenservice";

        var authHeader = string.Format("Basic {0}",
                                       Convert.ToBase64String(
                                           Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Uri.EscapeDataString(oAuthClientId) + ":" +
                                                                  Uri.EscapeDataString((oAuthClientSecret)))
                                           ));

        //passing code here
        var postBody = string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&code={0}", code);

        var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
        authRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", authHeader);
        authRequest.Method = "POST";
        byte[] postcontentsArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postBody);
        authRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
        authRequest.ContentLength = postcontentsArray.Length;

        try
        {
            using (Stream stream = authRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(postcontentsArray, 0, postcontentsArray.Length);
                stream.Close();

                WebResponse response = authRequest.GetResponse();
                using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    if (responseStream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            reader.Close();
                            responseStream.Close();
                            response.Close();
                            //this will return you access token which you can use to get user information
                            var responseResult =
                                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);                                
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //log error
        }
    }
```

After this you can call GET method with new token for user information, uri: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/identity/openidconnect/userinfo/?schema=openid

Refer to: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/direct/identity/log-in-with-paypal/

Answer (score 0):

Im having the same issue here, and Im trying your method.  However I'm getting a  a 400 Bad Request after being returned to my site, at the

```
WebResponse response = authRequest.GetResponse();
```

I've verified my clientId and secret is correct, and that an authCode is being returned successfully to the method.  Did you possibly also run into this issue?

Thanks

--- UPDATE ---

cleaned solution and browser cache and it does seem to work ok now

Answer (score 0):

Sailen's answer above worked for me. However, because Paypal changed their encryption to TLS in June 2016, the solution as it was written will return the following error

> The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Based on answers provided in another [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939523/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-sandbox-account), the `SecurityProtocol` needs to be set to `Tls12 before` creating the `WebRequest`. Hope this helps someone.

Here's a snippet.

```
var postBody = $"grant_type=authorization_code&code={code}";

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

var authRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(oAuthUrl);
```