# Paypal Login .Net API -- unhandled exception

Tags: .net, api, authentication, paypal

I am working with the Payapl Login .Net API following this example

https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/dotnet?success=true&env=sandbox

I can work through step 1 and get the browser to redirect to the Paypal login in step 2.  Once I log in (using my buyer account), I am sent back to my return_Uri, which is where the error is happening.

I am getting an "Unhandled Execution Error", and when inspecting the error in Visual Studio I am getting a blank error message and no further information about the error.

Here is the Step 3 portion of my code

var authCode = Request["code"];

```
        Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        configurationMap.Add("mode", "sandbox");

        PayPal.Api.APIContext apiContext = new PayPal.Api.APIContext();
        apiContext.Config = configurationMap;

        PayPal.Api.CreateFromAuthorizationCodeParameters param = new PayPal.Api.CreateFromAuthorizationCodeParameters();
        param.clientId = "XXXXXXX";
        param.clientSecret = "YYYYYYYY";
        param.SetCode(authCode);

        try
        {
            var info = PayPal.Api.Tokeninfo.CreateFromAuthorizationCode(apiContext, param);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            throw;
        }
```

I've made sure that my redirect URl matches what is in my developer account setup, and have even created a new App, as this seemed to solve an issue where the API was not recognizing my return URL that I was passing.

Have also made sure all my App Capabilites are set to return information, this is explained here [Using Paypal Login API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20833762/using-paypal-login-api), among other things.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

-- UPDATE --

this works as a solution

[Paypal OAuth login example doesn't work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352330/paypal-oauth-login-example-doesnt-work-as-expected/28553431#28553431)