# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel sandbox account

Tags: .net, paypal, sandbox

It was working well before a week but now it shows following error. I have tried the following things but of no use.

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

so suggest me with possible solution

```
public string HttpCall(string NvpRequest) //CallNvpServer
    {
        string url = pendpointurl;

        //To Add the credentials from the profile
        string strPost = NvpRequest + "&" + buildCredentialsNVPString();
        strPost = strPost + "&BUTTONSOURCE=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(BNCode);

        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        // allows for validation of SSL conversations
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };


        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        objRequest.Timeout = Timeout;
        objRequest.Method = "POST";
        objRequest.ContentLength = strPost.Length;

        try
        {
            using (StreamWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter(objRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                myWriter.Write(strPost);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            /*
            if (log.IsFatalEnabled)
            {
                log.Fatal(e.Message, this);
            }*/
        }

        //Retrieve the Response returned from the NVP API call to PayPal
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();
        string result;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        //Logging the response of the transaction
        /* if (log.IsInfoEnabled)
         {
             log.Info("Result :" +
                       " Elapsed Time : " + (DateTime.Now - startDate).Milliseconds + " ms" +
                      result);
         }
         */
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Any Updates on this ? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 38):

I just ran into this same problem in my testing environment as well (luckily my live payments are going through). I fixed it by changing:

```
public PayPalAPI(string specialAccount = "")
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

to

```
public PayPalAPI(string specialAccount = "")
{
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

They disabled support for SSL3 a while ago: https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/ssl-security-update, specifically stating

> Ensure you are connecting to PayPal endpoints using TLS 1.0 or 1.2
>   (not all API endpoints currently support TLS 1.1).

Their [latest update](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US) (thx for the comment update from @awesome) states:

> PayPal is updating its services to require TLS 1.2 for all HTTPS
>   connections. At this time, PayPal will also require HTTP/1.1 for all
>   connections... **To avoid any disruption of service, you must verify that your systems are ready for this change by June 17, 2016**

Comment: Official news https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1914&viewlocale=en_US

Comment: Thanks heaps! Just what I needed.

Answer (score 22):

Indeed changing **SecurityProtocolType.Tls**   fixes the problem, if you´re working in VS with a framework lower than 4.5 you won´t be able to change it, you have to upgrade your VS to a highest version 2012/2013/2015 to change it.

> System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
>   System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.**Tls12**;

Comment: Actually you *can* use it (in 4.0 at least) like this:
 `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072; // SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`

Comment: This is very very helpful @JamesMcCormack

Comment: Thanks, its working perfect for .Net 4.0 using ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;

please check-http://joymonscode.blogspot.in/2015/08/how-to-make-net-40-45-use-tls-12.html

Answer (score 11):

Add the following code to your global.asax or before calling the (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    // ...
}
```

This was caused because PayPal are changing their encryption to TLS instead of SSL. This has already been updated on the Sandbox environments but not yet on the live.

Read more: 
https://devblog.paypal.com/upcoming-security-changes-notice/

Answer (score 1):

If your framework version is less than 4.5, you might not be able to set it directly. You can use the below code

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```