# The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel While Sending Notification

Tags: .net, ssl, push-notification, notifications, ssl-certificate

This line shows me error.

```
WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();
dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();
```

I am using

```
{ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;}
```

as temporary solution.

Comment: Check this link [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939523/the-request-was-aborted-could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-sandbox-account)

Comment: I had already View that.Do i need to add certificate as well.